# Pygtk mount file through sftp without username and password dialog?

Tags: gtk, sftp, pygtk

I am trying to mount a directory via sftp in pygtk. Since I already have the username and password stored in variables, I don't want to get a dialog box asking for the username and password. I am using the following code:

```python
def error_printer(o,r)
    try:
        o.mount_enclosing_volume_finish(r)
    except gio.Error, e:
        print str(e.message),"error code:", e.code

myfile = gio.File("sftp://" + my_ip_address)
op = gtk.MountOperation()
op.set_username(my_username)
op.set_password(my_password)
my_file.mount_enclosing_volume(op, error_printer)
```

When I run this, a dialog box appears asking for the username and password even though I already set the username and password.

What do I do to make the dialog never appear and use the username and password I set instead?

(I am using pygtk 2.16)

Comment: Use `gio.MountOperation` instead of `gtk.MountOperation`?

Comment: I tried replacing `gtk.MountOperation()` with `gio.MountOperation()`. But then there's an error at `mount_enclosing_volume_finish` and  my `error_printer` prints  `"Password dialog cancelled error code: 30"`  and the directory doesn't mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!
Had to do it like [these guys:](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40d%40u%40duplicity-HEAD%40duplicity%40backends%40giobackend.py/51/gio.MountOperation/python)

```
class DupMountOperation(gio.MountOperation):
"""A simple MountOperation that grabs the password from the environment
   or the user.
"""
def __init__(self, backend):
    gio.MountOperation.__init__(self)
    self.backend = backend
    self.connect('ask-password', self.ask_password)

def ask_password(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.set_password(self.backend.get_password())
    self.reply(gio.MOUNT_OPERATION_HANDLED)
```